# DC motor - generator question

Tags: dc, dc-motor

[image: Circuit]

Both the motor and the generator are identical permanently excited DC motors and are running in constant torque mode.

Power IN is constant voltage.

When a load is connected at the generator terminals, 150V and 7.5A is measured (power out.) Ra is 2 Ohms.

What would be the relative change in speed to the initial setup when both the Ra are 4 Ohms ?

Comment: Homework question?  Where are you up to so far?

Comment: It was an exam question which I got wrong, but the explanation given by the professor was really confusing

Comment: What did the professor say?  Approximately?

Comment: He said we have to recalculate the current, the circuit he used to do so was 180V at motor in, 4 Ohms, 4Ohms and 20Ohms in series. From which we get 6.43A. (But since the motor are in constant torque the current shouldn't change, what I was questing and also since the current is depended on the induced voltage and we don't have that we can find the current the way he did)

Comment: I think that you can work backwards from the output- 7.5A is flowing and so Ra in the generator drops 15V so the power in the shaft is 7.5x165 = 1237.5W.  I guess if the motor also drops 15V then that would give 180V but I’m not sure what ‘running in constant torque mode’ means given that there’s no control circuit; the torque generally drops as speed increases.  Anyhoo, the load is 20 ohms, so change Ra to 4 ohms and then you have an effective series resistance of 8 ohms between input and output, so you’ll get 180/28A flowing and 180-8x(180/28)V across the load.  Is that making sense?

Comment: Explain what you think this "constant torque mode" is, and what would happen in that mode if you removed the load entirely.

Comment: The torque is going to be constant regardless of the speed of the rotor

Comment: Running at constant torque would mean that the torques is constant regardless of the speed of the rotor. That would mean the we won't have to recalculate the current. But there is a constant voltage source and it can't give out the same current(constant torque), but the current has to be the same. and I don't think so that there exist a power that can provide the same current and voltage

Comment: Yes Frog, I was able to get to the 180V at the motor terminals, but when we change Ra -> the speed of the rotor would change and the speed effects the induced voltage -> which effects the current. In order to find the current won't we be needing the induced voltage

Comment: Both of the machines have the same torque and speed. You don't know what the values are, but you can assume that they are 1 per unit for the initial conditions. You can also assume that the mechanical losses are negligible.